# SELECT COUNT function with TWO different conditions

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem where the SELECT COUNT function is not accepting multiple conditions and is returning "0".

As you can see, it works when the condition is singular but not when they are combined.

Is this even possible or am I making a mistake? From what I've seen this should be possible but just isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

Code below:

```
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*)
   ...> FROM Table
   ...> WHERE race = ' White';
167365
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*)
   ...> FROM Table
   ...> WHERE sex = ' Female';
103984
sqlite> SELECT COUNT(*)
   ...> FROM Table
   ...> WHERE race = ' White'
   ...> AND  sex = ' Female';
0
```

Comment: This is not your actual code, right? I don't believe that the table's name is `Table` and that there are leading spaces in the values of race and sex. Post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even possible or am I making a mistake? From what I've seen this should be possible but just isn't working.

Yes it does work, so it would appear that you have no data that has both race as ' White'  and sex = ' Female'.

e.g. :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, race TEXT, sex TEXT);

INSERT INTO example VALUES
    (1,' White', ' Male'),
    (2,' Black', ' Male'),
    (3,' White',' Female'),
    (4,' Black)',' Female')
;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example WHERE race = ' White';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example WHERE sex = ' Female';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example WHERE race = ' White' AND sex = ' Female';
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example;
```

Produces :-

[image],
[image] and
[image]

Obviously the issue appears that for some reason there are no rows that meet the criteria for whatever reason.

You could use something like :-

```
SELECT COUNT(*), '=>'||race AS race, '=>'||sex AS sex FROM example GROUP BY race,sex;
```

To find the issue(s). This would produce a result something along the lines of :-

[image]